# Quickest way to save new text file to a folder

Tags: finder

I have a folder open in finder - what is the quickest way to save a new text file to it?

On Windows I would use "New Text" and then edit the file. On the Mac I open a new file in Sublime or Textedit but then I have to select the folder again when I want to save ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following AppleScript through a service with keyboard shortcut or context menu item.

```
tell application "Finder"
  set selection to make new file at (get insertion location)
end tell
```

Alternatively, drag the current directory to Terminal and type `touch filename`. You can alias the command to something like `n` for easier activation, and also add closing the Terminal window to the aliased command.

Comment: I was hoping for a built in command as it's not always my own Mac where I need this. Thanks though!

Comment: This is built-in ! And it is the easiest I can think of.

Comment: @hcris There is no predefined new file built in method. This however, requires no external software. I have added another method though — see edit.

Comment: @grgarside After figuring out to drag to the Terminal dock icon instead of the window I really like your `touch` alternative! Thanks, that work's very well.

Answer (score 0):

Using terminal would be the quickest, all things considered.

Open a terminal and type `cd` (including a space) and drop the desired target directory into the terminal window, which will basically input the path directory, and hit enter. Then type `nano [filename]`, which will give you a text file to write in. When you're done, type ctrl-x (not cmd) to exit, and confirm filename to save to by hitting `y`.

Alternatively you can combine step one and two by entering `nano path/to/file.txt`.

Comment: An improvement to this would be to use dterm rather than the built in Terminal.app. Dterm will pop up a command line with the directory set to the folder of the current Finder window, which is handy for all sorts of things : http://decimus.net/dterm. You could just type 'touch filename.txt' in dterm, and a new empty text file would appear in the Finder window straight away, ready to be opened by whichever app you choose.

Comment: In a similar vein, [PathFinder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) is a vastly superior file browser for Mac, and allows opening a terminal window from the currently browsed directory with a single click, in addition to many more features that improve on Finder. In fact PathFinder has a right-click 'New File…' option as well. 

Though both Dterm and PathFinder are commercial non-free software.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I've found so far is to

- drag the current folder from the *Path Bar* to *Favorites*
- in Sublime/Textedit do *Save*, then select the folder from *Favorites*

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to Your `.bash_profile` file:

```
alias nf="eval \"cd \\\"\\\`osascript -e 'tell app \\\\\\\"Finder\\\\\\\" to return the POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)'\\\`\\\"\" && touch filename.txt && open filename.txt"
```

Then if You type `nf` in **Terminal.app** You will create new *txt* file in the location of the topmost **Finder** window and open it with Your default application.